# Unable to read database file asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I don't know why give me this error in the code:

> Unable to read database file

I get this error on line da.fill(dt)?

I'm trying to select from my database and display them in my DayPilotScheduler1.

```
private void loadResources()
{
    DayPilotScheduler1.Resources.Clear();

    string roomFilter = "0";
    if (DayPilotScheduler1.ClientState["filter"] != null)
    {
        roomFilter = (string)DayPilotScheduler1.ClientState["filter"]["room"];
    }
    SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Korisnik;Integrated Security=True");
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT [id], [name], [beds], [bath] FROM [RoomDetails] WHERE beds = @beds or @beds = '0'", con);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("beds", roomFilter);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        string name = (string)r["name"];
        string id = (string)r["id"];
        string bath = (string)r["bath"];
        int beds = Convert.ToInt32(r["beds"]);
        string bedsFormatted = (beds == 1) ? "1 bed" : String.Format("{0} beds", beds);

        Resource res = new Resource(name, id);
        res.Columns.Add(new ResourceColumn(bedsFormatted));
        res.Columns.Add(new ResourceColumn(bath));

        DayPilotScheduler1.Resources.Add(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the complete exception > sorry for not posting this as comment but have not enought rep :)

Comment: Use SqlConnection, not SQLiteConnection.

Comment: Are you using windows 7? try running Visual Studio as an Administrator...

Comment: And use the config file to store the connection string!

Comment: Can you tell how to put connection string in config file, and then how to call the connection string in sql statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your connection string you're connecting to a SQL Server Express database, not a SQLite database.

Use a `SqlConnection` instead of `SQLiteConnection` (along with the corresponding DataAdapter, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever thisn type of error arises, then there is a possibility of having errors in the connectionstring, so trace your web.config file.
In your above code, you have mentioned **Sqliteconnection** which should be **Sqlconnection**, and make the corresponding changes in the code.